# бот Discord не выводит из текстового файла русский текст

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import *
import os
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

bot_token = "" #скрыл по понятным причинам
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/",intents=discord.Intents.all())
prefix = "/"

@bot.command(alies=["1"], pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def Shut_your_mouth(ctx):
    f = open("baze/shut your mouth.txt", "r")
    await ctx.send(f.read())

bot.run(bot_token)
```

Мы наблюдаем, что если в текстовом документе содержится текст на английском, то его выводит без проблем. Но если это русский текст, то выводит непонятно что. Как это можно решить?
[image: описание]

Также попробовал добавить следующее:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import *
import os
from youtube_dl import YoutubeDL

bot_token = "" #скрыл по понятным причинам
bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="/",intents=discord.Intents.all())
prefix = "/"

@bot.command(alies=["1"], pass_context = True)
@commands.has_permissions(administrator = True)
async def Shut_your_mouth(ctx):
    f = open("baze/shut your mouth.txt", "r", enconding='utf-8')
    await ctx.send(f.read())

bot.run(bot_token)
```

Но выводит ошибку:

```
C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\python.exe C:\Users\burak\Desktop\Extreme\bot.py 
[2022-10-23 23:01:53] [INFO    ] discord.client: logging in using static token
[2022-10-23 23:01:54] [INFO    ] discord.gateway: Shard ID None has connected to Gateway (Session ID: e19c03d138736d7d08279e6f803ec798).
Get ready.
[2022-10-23 23:01:59] [ERROR   ] discord.ext.commands.bot: Ignoring exception in command Shut_your_mouth
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 190, in wrapped
    ret = await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\burak\Desktop\Extreme\bot.py", line 60, in Shut_your_mouth
    f = open("baze/shut your mouth.txt", "r", enconding='utf-8')
TypeError: 'enconding' is an invalid keyword argument for open()

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\bot.py", line 1347, in invoke
    await ctx.command.invoke(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 986, in invoke
    await injected(*ctx.args, **ctx.kwargs)  # type: ignore
  File "C:\Users\burak\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\discord\ext\commands\core.py", line 199, in wrapped
    raise CommandInvokeError(exc) from exc
discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: 'enconding' is an invalid keyword argument for open()
```

Comment: open('baze/shut your mouth.txt"', 'r', encoding='utf-8')

Comment: Все правильно пробовали сделать, просто параметр называется не `'enconding'`, а `encoding`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Когда вы выводите текст, добавьте `encoding = <тип вашей кодировки>`, то есть, я выводил текст из блокнота (.txt), значит, кодировка UTF-8:

```py
async def Shut_your_mouth(ctx):
    f = open("baze/shut your mouth.txt", "r", encoding='utf-8')
    await ctx.send(f.read())
```

**Будьте внимательны!** Не `enconding`, а `encoding`.

Результат: [image: описание]